# directory tree in Code Runner for Mac

Tags: macos, text-editors

I'm using the [CodeRunner app for Mac](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/coderunner/id433335799?mt=12).

On the left hand side, there is a directory of my computer's file system. All of my coding projects are in `/Users/ME/Sites`, but the directory in CodeRunner shows a much higher level, so there's a lot of unnecessary folders shown on my screen, and if I try to open a project in `/Users/ME/Sites`, it ends up creating a massive sprawl (for example, there are hundreds of folders inside the "sites" folder) on the left side as I navigate to a project.

My question is, is there a way that I can have the left side of CodeRunner display just the directory for a particular project, as, for example, I can do in Sublime Text or any other reputable code editor?

[image: screenshot of the left panel]

Comment: Well, given that the screenshots indicate it can be different... have you tried clicking the icons to the lower left, below the sidebar? Or on "Volumes"? In one of the screenshots, it seems to be a button. Unfortunately I don't own it and there's no trial version.

Comment: Yes, I can click on Users, for example, but then it opens up a whole subdirectory etc, inside of which I have further subdirectories, but if I do that, all these top levels remain. All I wish to do is open a subdirectory at a time